# How to populate the html table when date is set

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a table which will get populated with data according to the search date. My search is working but the problem I'm having is how to get all that data into HTML table.

Below is my code which kept trying different ways.

HTML:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../iConnect/handShake.php");
include_once ("../Functions/userCheck.php");
//TODO write the SQL to accept and retrieve the data

if (isset($_REQUEST["date"])){
    $getJobs = "SELECT * FROM usertimetrack WHERE jDate = :jDate";
    $getJobsQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($getJobs);
    $getJobsQuery -> bindParam(':jDate', $_REQUEST["date"]);
    $getJobsQuery -> execute();
}

//$getJobs = "SELECT * FROM usertimetrack ORDER BY utId ASC";
//$getJobsQuery = $dbConnect -> query($getJobs);
?>

<html>
<head>

    <!-- Style Sheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../CSS/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../CSS/jquery-ui.min.css">

    <!-- Java Scripts -->
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/editTimeEntryFunctions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divCenter" class="box">

    <div class="logo">
        <img src="../../images/logo.png" width="142" height="33">
    </div>
    <div id="mainDiv">
        <div id="navi"></div>
        <div id="infoi"></div>
        <label for="dPicker">Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="dPicker" style="margin-left: .5%;" size="10">
        <input type="button" class="getData" value="Submit">
        <table id="hor-minimalist-b">
            <div id="bgDimmer"></div>
            <div id="divContent"></div>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">User Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Category</th>
                <th scope="col">Client</th>
                <th scope="col">Start Time</th>
                <th scope="col">End Time</th>
                <th scope="col">Time Spent</th>
                <th scope="col">Volume</th>
                <th scope="col">Prod. Lines</th>
                <th scope="col">Remarks</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php while ($getJobsRow = $getJobsQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["utId"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["usrId"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["Category"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["Client"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["startTime"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["endTime"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["timeSpent"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["Volume"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["noOfProductLines"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["Remarks"]; ?></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="uEdit" value="Edit" data-uid="<?php echo $getJobsRow["utId"]; ?>" /></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="uDel" value="Delete" data-uid="<?php echo $getJobsRow["utId"]; ?>" /></a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="msg"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to use the below JavaScript submit the data to the same page it does work according to the browser console but it doesn't get loaded into the visible page.

JavaScript:

```
function getData(){

    var date = document.getElementById("dPicker").value;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){

        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

    }else{

        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST","../functions/editTimeEntry.php?date="+date,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

When the above code didn't work I have tried to do it using JQuery which was a dead end.

**EDIT:** Let me make this more simple is there any way to archive the below dirty PHP method using JavaScript or any other.

Script:

```
<div align="right" style="background-color:#CCC" class="noprint">
        <input type="text" id="loomDate" name="loomDate" value="---Select Loom Date---" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('*[name=loomDate]').appendDtpicker(
                    {
                        'dateFormat' : 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                        'dateOnly': true,
                        'closeOnSelected': true,
                        'autodateOnStart': false
                    }
                );
            });
        </script>
        <input type="button" id="Search" name="Search" value="Search" onclick="this.form.submit()" />
        <input type="button" id="Print" name="Print" VALUE="Print" onclick="window.print()" />
    </div>
```

Can someone please guide me down the path of light.

**UPDATE:**
Someone did show me the light so I'm going to share it with you guys here.

Finally found how to get this done thanks to PHP freshers so below is the code I'm using currently need to be refined but still, it has the basic idea.

HTML: (Main Page)

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once ("../Functions/userCheck.php");
?>

<html>
<head>

    <!-- Style Sheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../CSS/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../CSS/jquery-ui.min.css">

    <!-- Java Scripts -->
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/editTimeEntryFunctions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="divCenter" class="box">

    <div class="logo">
        <img src="../../images/logo.png" width="142" height="33">
    </div>
    <div id="mainDiv">
        <label for="dPicker">Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="dPicker" style="margin-left: .5%;" size="10">
        <input type="button" class="getData" value="Submit" onclick="getData();">
    </div>
    <div id="table"></div>
</div>
<div id="msg"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML / PHP: (Display Page)

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../iConnect/handShake.php");
include_once ("../Functions/userCheck.php");
//TODO write the SQL to accept and retrieve the data

if (isset($_REQUEST["date"])){
    $getJobs = "SELECT * FROM usertimetrack WHERE jDate = :jDate";
    $getJobsQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($getJobs);
    $getJobsQuery -> bindParam(':jDate', $_REQUEST["date"]);
    $getJobsQuery -> execute();
}

//$getJobs = "SELECT * FROM usertimetrack ORDER BY utId ASC";
//$getJobsQuery = $dbConnect -> query($getJobs);
?>

<html>
<head>

    <!-- Style Sheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../CSS/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../CSS/jquery-ui.min.css">

    <!-- Java Scripts -->
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/editTimeEntryFunctions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainDiv">
        <div id="navi"></div>
        <div id="infoi"></div>
        <table id="hor-minimalist-b">
            <div id="bgDimmer"></div>
            <div id="divContent"></div>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">ID</th>
                <th scope="col">User Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Category</th>
                <th scope="col">Client</th>
                <th scope="col">Start Time</th>
                <th scope="col">End Time</th>
                <th scope="col">Time Spent</th>
                <th scope="col">Volume</th>
                <th scope="col">Prod. Lines</th>
                <th scope="col">Remarks</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php while ($getJobsRow = $getJobsQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["utId"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["usrId"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["Category"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["Client"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["startTime"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["endTime"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["timeSpent"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["Volume"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["noOfProductLines"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["Remarks"]; ?></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="uEdit" value="Edit" data-uid="<?php echo $getJobsRow["utId"]; ?>" /></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="uDel" value="Delete" data-uid="<?php echo $getJobsRow["utId"]; ?>" /></a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#dPicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        showAnim: 'slide'
    });
});

function getData(){

    var date = document.getElementById("dPicker").value;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){

        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

    }else{

        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

            document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST","../functions/timeEditResult.php?date="+date,true);
    xmlhttp.send();}
```

If anyone wants to know I'm using [Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) for my date picker it's a very good Jquery library.

And hope this helps someone in future.

Comment: Seems like you didn't write the code to show the result in javascript code.
Add this code..`document.getElementById("show_result_div").innerHTML = this.responseText;`

Comment: @phpfresher I did had a line like that but removed it because I wanted to load the data in to the same page as the date picker. So according to your suggestion I should have another DIV and call the above HTML page in to that using the `inner.HTML`?.

Comment: Seems like you are making the request using AJAX. So ajax gives you the response with `responseText`, and so you should show it somewhere using javascript itself. You can put your table in a DIV and show the result in that DIV. So that the old data will be replaced with the new data.

Comment: @phpfresher Thank you for the comments ok will try something like that and let you know I made an update to question as well to make it more understandable.

Comment: @phpfresher Thank you, you showed me the light should have done it earlier.

Comment: you are welcome :-)